# Hadoop Iterator skip method call at first iteration

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, iterator

I have a Map Reduce program and in the Reducer class my method is not called in the first iteration. What I want to achieve is to generate some new rows between every 2 consecutive values from the iterator. (pairs like: (1,2),(2,3),(3,4)...). What am I missing? And I also tested that I have the pairs like I need and it looks fine, but it seems that my method is not called for the first pair..
generate() - will generate new rows between every 2 consecutive rows(filling the time gap)

`input:
X, Y, 00:00:00, 908
X, Y, 00:00:05, 122
X, Y, 00:00:07, 123`

`desired output:
X, Y, 00:00:00, 908
X, Y, 00:00:01, 908
X, Y, 00:00:02, 908
X, Y, 00:00:03, 908
X, Y, 00:00:04, 908
X, Y, 00:00:05, 122
X, Y, 00:00:06, 122
X, Y, 00:00:07, 123`

```
Iterator<MyType> iterator = values.iterator();
if (!iterator.hasNext()) return;
first = iterator.next();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   nr++;
   first.setStatus(nr);
   context.write(nullWritable, first);
   second = iterator.next();
   List<MyType> newValues = generate(first, second, context);
   for (MyType mt : newValues) {
          mt.setStatus(nr);
          context.write(nullWritable, mt);
    }
   second.setStatus(nr);
   context.write(nullWritable, second);
   first = new InterpolationModelWritable();
   first.setX(second.getX());
   first.setY(second.getY());
   first.setZ(second.getZ());
   first.setTag(second.getTag());

 }
```

`actual result:
X, Y, 00:00:00, 908
X, Y, 00:00:05, 122
X, Y, 00:00:06, 122
X, Y, 00:00:07, 123`

Comment: Can you expand on your question, its really not clear what your after and what the problem is. If i wanted to test your code, would that be possible based on what you've provided? I would need example input, output and your expected output. You call a `generate` method, what does that do?

Comment: @Binary Nerd  you can see now my updates

Comment: Can you add the logic for your generate method.

Comment: I am afraid I can't. But it works perfectly on other input rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're falling into the hadoop object reuse trap. The important thing to remember is that the values iterator in a reduce isn't returning a new object each time you call `next()`, its reusing the same object.

Now we know that we can take a look at your code and work out whats wrong. Using your logic (but as a minimal working example) we can see that *normally* it would work.

```
@Test
public void noResuseIteratorTest() {

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("a");
    values.add("b");
    values.add("c");
    values.add("d");

    String first;
    String second;

    Iterator<String> iterator = values.iterator();
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return;
    first = iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        second = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Out: " + first + " - " + second);
        first = second;
    }
}
```

> Out: a - b
>   Out: b - c
>   Out: c - d

However, in an hadoop reduce method the returned value is the same object. This test demonstrates the problem:

```
@Test
public void reuseIteratorTest() {

    class MyList implements Iterable<Text> {

        private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        private Text reused = new Text();

        public MyList() {
            myList.add("a");
            myList.add("b");
            myList.add("c");
            myList.add("d");
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Text> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Text> () {

                private final Iterator<String> iter = myList.iterator();

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iter.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public Text next() {
                    // We reuse the Text object here!
                    reused.set(iter.next());
                    return reused;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("");
                }
            };
        }
    }

    MyList myList = new MyList();
    Text first;
    Text second;

    Iterator<Text> iterator = myList.iterator();
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return;
    first = iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        second = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Out: " + first + " - " + second);
        first = new Text();
        first.set(second);
    }
}
```

> Out: b - b
>   Out: b - c
>   Out: c - d

So, simply doing `second = iterator.next();` isn't good enough. In your first iteration both `first` and `second` are pointing at the same object.

To fix this you need to be copying the contents of the iterators value into your objects and not just pointing to the same object. Using Text objects as an example, the fixed version would look like:

```
@Test
public void reuseFixedIteratorTest() {

    // MyList class from above goes here

    MyList myList = new MyList();
    Text first = new Text();
    Text second = new Text();

    Iterator<Text> iterator = myList.iterator();
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return;
    first.set(iterator.next());
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        second.set(iterator.next());
        System.out.println("Out: " + first + " - " + second);
        first.set(second);
    }
}
```

> Out: a - b
>   Out: b - c
>   Out: c - d

Comment: save my week! Thank you! @Binary Nerd